# Failing to copy memory in my wpf app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-management, mvvm

I am a C++ developer and I recently started working on WPF. I am working on series of comboboxes and a button. here is the code:

XAML:

```
<GroupBox Header="EEPROM Version Strings" Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,0,10,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Content="Write EEPROM" Command="{Binding WriteEEPROMCommand}" Grid.Row="4" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="WriteEEPROMVersionStrings" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="116" />
                <ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding I2CAddressList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedI2CAddressList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" />
                <ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding BoardBoxList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBoardBoxList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" />
                <ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding VersionBoxList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVersionBoxList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="comboBox3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" />
                <ComboBox Height="23" ItemsSource="{Binding SerialBoxList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSerialBoxList, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="comboBox4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" />
            </Grid>                    
        </GroupBox>
```

Since I am using MVVM, Here is my ViewModel Class:

```
Byte[] sendBuf = new Byte[256];
    Byte[] readBuf = new Byte[256];       

    public ObservableCollection<string> _I2CAddressList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> _BoardBoxList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> _VersionBoxList;
    public ObservableCollection<string> _SerialBoxList;
```

In Constructor:

```
var myboard = new[]
        {      
               "",
               "S1010012",   // redhook
               "S1010018",   // bavaria
               "S1010020"    // flying dog
        };

        var myVariant = new[]
        { 
               "",    
               "001A",
               "001B",
               "001C",
               "002A",
               "002B",
               "002C",
               "003A",
               "003B",
               "003C",
        };      

        _I2CAddressList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        _BoardBoxList = new ObservableCollection<string>(myboard);
        _VersionBoxList = new ObservableCollection<string>(myVariant);
        _SerialBoxList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 200; i++)
        {
            _SerialBoxList.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        //List of I2C Address
        _I2CAddressList.Add("0x50");
        _I2CAddressList.Add("0x53");

        this.SelectedI2CAddressList = this._I2CAddressList[1];
        this.SelectedBoardBoxList = this.BoardBoxList[2];
        this.SelectedVersionBoxList = this.VersionBoxList[2];
        this.SelectedSerialBoxList = this.SerialBoxList[0];
```

Here goes the combobox and button property:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> I2CAddressList
    {
        get { return _I2CAddressList; }
        set
        {
            _I2CAddressList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("I2CAddressList");
        }
    }

    private string _SelectedI2CAddressList;
    public string SelectedI2CAddressList
    {
        get { return _SelectedI2CAddressList; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedI2CAddressList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedI2CAddressList");
        }
    }        

    // Similar property for other comboboxes

    private ICommand mWriteEEPROMCommand;
    public ICommand WriteEEPROMCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (mWriteEEPROMCommand == null)
                mWriteEEPROMCommand = new DelegateCommand(new Action(mWriteEEPROMCommandExecuted), new Func<bool>(mWriteEEPROMCommandCanExecute));

            return mWriteEEPROMCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            mWriteEEPROMCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public bool mWriteEEPROMCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return true;
    }

    char[] version = 
        {
                'A', 'U', 'D', 'I', 'E', 'N', 'C', 'E',         // name
                '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ,        // reserved,  firmware size
                '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ,        // board number
                '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ,        // variant, version, serial
                '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'          // date code, reserved
        };               

    public void mWriteEEPROMCommandExecuted()
    {
        int temp, memloc = 0;
        int cmd = 0x0A53;

        // fill in the I2C address
        if ((I2CAddressList.IndexOf(_SelectedI2CAddressList) + 1) == 1)
        {
            cmd = 0x0A50;
        }

        // fill in the address to write to -- 0
        sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;
        sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;   

        // fill in the audience header
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            sendBuf[i + memloc] = Convert.ToByte(version[i]);       // the first 8 bytes
        }               
        memloc += 16;                                               // the 8 copied, plus 8 reserved bytes

        temp = (BoardBoxList.IndexOf(_SelectedBoardBoxList) + 1);
        if (temp >= 1 && temp <= 3) 
        {
            // How to perform the memory operation here
        }

        memloc += 8;            // move regardless if this was set
    }
```

I am not able to figure out how can i perform the memory operation on `myboard`. Although I was able to do it on `version`. This is how I had done it in C++ code

```
sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;
    sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;

    // fill in the audience header
    memcpy(sendBuf+memloc, version, 8); // the first 8 bytes
    memloc += 16;

temp = m_boardBox->getSelectedId();
    if(temp >= 1 && temp <= 3) // a valid board selection
        memcpy(sendBuf+memloc, boards[temp], 8);
    memloc += 8;
```

where boards is like this:

```
static const signed char boards[][9] = {
{},                                           // left blank to indicate no selection
{ 'S', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '2', 0 },   // redhook
{ 'S', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '8', 0 },   // bavaria
{ 'S', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '2', '0', 0 },   // flying dog
```

};

Thus when I click WRITEEEPROM Button, the series of code is executed. I have been succesful to someextent but when I came across how to copy memory for array of strings, i couldnt solve it. I have shown the C++ sample above :)

How can I achieve it???

Comment: You should try to provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/). This is a lot of code to go through and I fail to see how everything is related to your problem.

Comment: @Default Well I just wanted to give a clear picture of my combobox, items which I am adding, properties associated with it and the operation I need to perform on a button click :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for, but I'll try anyway.

Strings are encoded using [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.text.encoding.aspx) class. This class provides methods to convert a string into a byte array using a specified encoding:

```
Byte[] encodedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("string");
```

Several encodings are provided by the framework itself, e.g. ASCII, UTF7, UTF8, Unicode and so on. If you need a special encoding, you have to implement it on your own using Encoding as your base class.

The resulting Byte-Array can be copied into your send buffer using `System.Buffer`.

Comment: Well thats right. If you have a look at `temp = m_boardBox->getSelectedId();
    if(temp >= 1 && temp <= 3) 
        memcpy(sendBuf+memloc, boards[temp], 8);` you will find me accessing a string present inside `boards`. Lets say `temp = 2`, it will select `S1010018` from it and perform `memcpy`. Keeping that in mind, how can I select an item from array of string and then encode? :) Would appreciate if you can demonstrate it with a code :)

Comment: @StevenWilson To select an item from an array of string you can use `string s = arrayOfString[itemID];`

Comment: if you notice my `myboard`is in constructor. Since I am trying to access it in my method like string s = myboard[2], It says `myboard` is not present in this context.

Comment: @StevenWilson Have you tried to make it an instance variable?

Comment: In this case I advise you to learn the basics of coding. Sorry, but this seems a bit to mediocre to me.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, System.Buffer contains a bunch of methods for copying buffers around.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.aspx

Comment: Have a look at how I have done for `version` and then have a look at `myboard`. I am not able to figure out how do I use perform the similar operation :( I would appreciate if you can demonstrate the issue with a sample code :)